# Thymeleaf - Get attribute value

Tags: java, html, spring, templates, thymeleaf

### The Problem

I want to pass some values from custom data-* tags (which were included there through javascript) that should be processed by my Spring controller.

Setting those values through Thymeleaf is no big deal, reading them when submitting a form **is a problem indeed**.

When I read the value directly from the input fields, there is no problem, but that is not an option for me because I want to pass extra data, "hidden" for the normal user.

Is it even possible to get the value of an attribute by using Thymeleaf?

---

### The code

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-text-field-fix" name="id" 
    id="id" placeholder="Identification" 
    required="" th:attr="data-column=*{id_column}" />
```

I want to read the value of the data-column attribute by using my Spring controller here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this.

`<input type="hidden" />` elements are built specifically for passing data like this, why do you want to do something else?

Answer (score 0):

I think it cant be achieved as we cant get Html element in Controller(In server).

Have an extra attribute for every hidden field in the Command object which is holding the form data, So that we can access that hidden attribute in the spring controller as other normal attribute.